# Filling a Big Table Rows from JSON Data

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fill up a table using JSON data

Here's what I am thinking

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "music.json"
})
.done(function(gamesjson){
    DATA = gamesjson;
    buildTable(DATA ); // this one is calling the above code
  })
.fail(function(){
    console.log("music.json error");
  })
;

function buildTable(DATA){
var gl = $("#gl");
$.each(DATA.music, function(index, value) {
// code to populate table
??

}

$("#gl").append(gl);
}
```

What do I write in buildTable()? **Also if my json contains 1000 rows, what's the best way to build table?**

***Please give an example and explanation. Thanks***

http://jsfiddle.net/9u4zR/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function buildTable(DATA){
    var table = "<table>";
    $.each(DATA.music, function(index, value) {
        table += "<tr><td>" + value.col1 + "</td><td>" + value.col2 + "</td></tr>";
    }
    table += "</table>";
    $("#gl").append(table);    
}
```

Of course, you need to replace `col1` and `col2` with the names of your actual properties, and add more columns as needed. You'll also probably want to specify classes or styles. But this shows you the general structure, you can refine it as needed for your application.

Comment: thanks barmar. As you can see, if there are 10 columns to fill the HTML will get messed up. One user answered to use templates. Do you have an example for that?

Comment: Why will the HTML get messed up if there are 10 colums to fill? I don't use any template systems, so I can't advise you. He told you a template system, I'm sure its web site has examples.

Comment: I meant this: table += "<tr><td>" + value.col1 + "</td><td>" + value.col2 + "</td></tr> + value.col3 + "</td></tr> + value.col4 + "</td></tr> + value.col5 + "</td></tr> + value.col6 + "</td></tr> + value.col7 + "</td></tr> + value.col8 + "</td></tr>"

Comment: You should only have one `</tr>` -- it should be at the end of the line. Don't you see that you're just constructing HTML? You do it the same as if you were creating the table by hand in an editor.

Comment: You're also missing some quotes.

Answer (score 0):

use **java script template**  technique  it will help you to render your JSON response on client side, I'm use **doT.js**  with php , it help you create your html template and bind an object to it