# Select rows based on header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a table

```
<table id="report">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first_name">First Name</th>
            <th class="last_name">Last Name</th>
            <th class="email">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>Hughes</td>
            <td>larry@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mike</td>
            <td>Tyson</td>
            <td>mike@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select all rows based on the header that is passed to a function. Here's what I mean

```
function passTh(nm){
   // for eg: nm will contain the class of the th "first_name"
   var th = "." + nm;
   // get index of th
   // i have to select all cells in this column along with the header and hide them
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "select cells in that column"?

Comment: yes I meant that..sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
$(function(){
    var $table = $('#report');
    function passTh(nm) {
        var th = "." + nm;
        var idx = $(th).index();
        $table.find('tr :nth-child(' + (idx+1) + ')').hide();
    }
    passTh('first_name');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A532E/)**

Since you want to hide th and tr you can select them with `nth-child` which takes elements based on index with base 1.

*UPDATE*

Since you have a large table, you can make it more effective with the help of css.

Your Html:

```
<table id="report">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first_name">First Name</th>
            <th class="last_name">Last Name</th>
            <th class="email">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="first_name">Larry</td>
            <td class="last_name">Hughes</td>
            <td class="email">larry@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first_name">Mike</td>
            <td class="last_name">Tyson</td>
            <td class="email">mike@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Add this Css:

```
#report.first_name_hide .first_name,
#report.last_name_hide .last_name,
#report.email_hide .email
{
    display:none;
}
```

And just this JS which just adds a class on to a table:

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('#report');
   function passTh(nm) {
        var hide = nm + "_hide";
        $table.addClass(hide);
    }
    passTh('first_name');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XejLC/)**

Comment: perfect..can you explain the code. Also in a big table, can find() be slow? How about $('table td:nth-child(' + index + 1 + ')').hide() or should I use the approach you suggested?

Comment: @user1089173 find will always be faster than using multiple nested selectors. One thing you can do to make it fast it to assign the same class to all the tr's. start up and just hide them with that selection. That will be much faster.

Comment: perfect. Thank you sir. Can you also look at this plz (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460581/filling-a-big-table-rows-from-json-data). I am sure you know a better way

Comment: you said add same class to all tr's. If that was the case, how will you code change. Something like var th = "." + nm; $(th).hide()? How do I pass the table id also here in case there are multiple tables

Comment: @user1089173 you can make it configurable. But can you change your table structure can you add some cssclass to your tds? Then we can handle it with css itself with little bit of js.

Comment: @user1089173 also do you want to suport older browsers?

Comment: Yes old browsers would be nice to have. Can you give both soln - one for new browsers and change reqs for old browsers

Comment: nice..another way I was thinking was, let's say I get the class to hide like this var thtohide = "." + nm; Is there any way I can pass this to a table. Pseudo code $(#table thtohide).hide()? Is this possible? Assuming all tr's in that column have the same class

Comment: figured it out. Let me know if it's ok var thtohide= "table#report ." + nm; $(thtohide).hide(); Is this code ok performance wise?

Comment: @user1089173 since you are adding the class to all of the td guys better go with just css, you can event get transition animation with css, hide just adds display:none you can better do it with css acc to me.

Comment: yes sure I will do it the css way but let's say for some reason I want to use only jquery, does this code look ok to you var thtohide = "table#report ." + nm; $(thtohide).hide();

Comment: awesome..If you have the time, can you answer his thread too. Think of it as an independent thread than this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460581/filling-a-big-table-rows-from-json-data .

Comment: @user1089173 Barmar's answer is good since you dont want to append to DOM for each item, instead do it in the end constructing a string which is the fastest poss way acc to me . Just tweaked his answer a bit check this http://jsfiddle.net/JPn5Z/

Comment: So when are templates used, you line jsRender and stuff?

Comment: Can you also please add some comments to that code especially for "$.each(data, function (_, value) {" and "debugger"..what do they do. Thanks so much